# App Not Being Deployed to Nokia Lumia Icon

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to debug my app to my Lumia Icon, but Visual Studio <del>stops</del> **hangs at "Deploy started"**.  I end up having to cancel the build to continue working.  It gets deployed just fine to my Lumia 635 and Blu Win JR though.  I don't know what's going wrong because I never get any error message.  My phone is connected correctly, and the Windows Phone app recognizes it.

Thanks

Comment: Just to rule it out, did you register your Lumia Icon as a developer's device?

Comment: What do you mean *VS stops*? (hangs?) Have you checked properties of your project (Properties -> Debug -> don't start app when it's deployed)?

Comment: @Romasz After it shows 'Deploy started...' in the status bar, nothing else happens.  I have to cancel the build to do anything else.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware Yes, it is registered.  This is strange because I've debugged apps on this phone before.

Comment: Do you have also installed a beta version from the store (with the same app id)? Also can you try to remove the app from the phone, clean the project in VS, unplug the phone, restart the phone, restart VS, plug the phone to different USB port, try to run?

Comment: @Romasz I've tried all of that, still nothing :/

Comment: I have the same problem now on a phone I´ve been developing with for a year. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a different micro USB cable and the app is now being deployed successfully.